# remove last node or specific node from nodelist without changing class or attribute in html

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible or is there any logic on how to remove specific node in nodelist?
I tried to use pop() out of nowhere thinking that it would work and i just laughed at my self.

Anyway,

I have this nodelist looks like this :

```
0: input#quesNameMLCTS
1: input#choicesTextAMLCTS
2: input#choicesTextBMLCTS
3: input#choicesTextCMLCTS
4: input#choicesTextDMLCTS
5: input#choicesTextCorrectMLCTS
```

I want to remove 3 and 5. is there any possible way to do that without modifying in HTML CODE?

Expected output looks like this :

```
0: input#quesNameMLCTS
1: input#choicesTextAMLCTS
2: input#choicesTextBMLCTS
3: input#choicesTextDMLCTS
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any method available to [mutate a NodeList](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#nodelist) (or even [an HTMLCollection](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-htmlcollection)) unless the collection happens to be *live* (such that changes to the nodes in the document result in changes to the collection) - so if you want to keep the existing nodes in the document as-is, there's no way to restructure the collection.

That said, it'd be pretty simple to convert it to an array, then change the array however you want.

```
// Take a NodeList and convert it into an array
const inputs = [...document.querySelectorAll('input')];

// Remove a single element at index 5 from the array
inputs.splice(5, 1);
```

Comment: Is there any difference between using spread ops then splice and spread ops then filter? What is the correct way or safest method?

Comment: Either work. Just keep in mind that `.splice` mutates the existing array, `.filter` returns a new array.